# Access denied if running .exe file with PSExec, while approved if running it without PSExec

Tags: c#, access-denied, psexec

I have some virtual machines (VM's) and I need them to copy some logs to a shared folder. 
I wrote a program in c# that copies files from a local location to the shared folder, and I am running the exe file of the it in the VM.
If I enter the VM and run the exe **manually**, everything works **great**.
But if I run it from PSExec, the program works well till the moment it needs to copy - and then I get access denied to the shared folder.

My Psexec command:

```
psexec \\hostName -s -h -u user -p password start file.exe
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Are you running as an administrator when in the vm running the exe manually? This could easily explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: @MarkMcWhirter I checked without running it as an admin and it worked well, so thats not the difference.